# I want to remove create an account link and add custom modal pop up link

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5-p1

I have tried below code but its not working. I am using default luma theme.I have added code in **app/design/frontend/Magento/layout/default.xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
</body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

OR Using CSS

```
.header.panel > .header.links > .authorization-link:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Devidas but code is not working.  My path is **app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**. Also as I update the question I need to override the link and add another link for modal pop up.